# I want to remove ' from numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to remove the value of '' while creating the numpy array
In the following situation, how can I remove the quotation mark that comes out by multiplying the 'character' by 0 and leave only 'character'?

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array(['character'*1,'character'*0])
```

**Expected**
array(['character'], dtype='<U9')

```
np.delete(array ,"''")
```

IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Comment: Your code creates strings that have no quotation marks *inside* them. A string can be written with quotation marks *around* it in Python code, but that's different from quotation marks inside them. What are you actually trying to do? It's unclear to me, sorry.

Comment: What about `array[array != '']`?

Comment: It has nothing to do with numpy. It is just related to lists. Numpy just converts the list into a numpy array.

Comment: @FatemehSangin - If `numpy` is used, it facilitates broadcasting to view only the populated elements.  Lists are not capable of this. Really depends on the need for scalability.

Comment: You have to give `np.delete` an index, not a value.  lists have a remove by value.  You question would be clearer if you showed `array`.  Most us don't  multiply strings by 0 very often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this in different ways,

here is one example:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([ele for ele in ['character'*1,'character'*0] if len(ele) > 0])
# or
array = np.array([ele for ele in ['character'*1,'character'*0] if ele != ''])
```

And to get your method working:

```
array = np.delete(array, array=='')
```

*EDIT*

And for @S3DEV:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array(['character'*1,'character'*0])
array = array[array != '']
```

Comment: There should be no need to iterate the array.  Broadcasting should be sufficient.

Comment: O yes, but there are numerous different methods how this can be solved.

Comment: True.  However, some solutions scale more efficiently.  ;-)